# pull records from cpanel's latest visitor php

Tags: php, cpanel

Have you ever tried to code to get all the visitors from the cpane's latest visitor?
Is this possible?

Comment: nobody seems to know? or this wasnt done before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little poking around the CPanel API site showed that what your looking for is the `listlastvisitors` function in the `ApiStats` module (API2).  From my memories of the CPanel API, it takes a lot of poking around through an amazing multitude of pages to get the API code to work in PHP, but if your up for a challenge, [Here's the module](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiStats#Stats%3a%3alistlastvisitors), and information about calling the API functions is [here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi).  Poke around the XML API, and check out API2.  Good luck, you will need it!